# Missing duration metadata for video merged by FFmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, metadata

There is no duration etc. in the metadata of video combined by FFmpeg on Android.

The metadata is gotten by executing the following command.

```
    -i C:\Users\ebiyuu1209\Desktop\test2.mp4 -f ffmetadata 
    C:\Users\ebiyuu1209\Desktop\metadata.txt
```

The log is as follows.

```
    ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
      libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
      libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
      libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
      libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
      libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
      libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
      libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
      libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\ebiyuu1209\Desktop\test2.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
      Duration: 00:03:00.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2739 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2478 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Output #0, ffmetadata, to 'C:\Users\ebiyuu1209\Desktop\metadata.txt':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream mapping:
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
    video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
    Output file is empty, nothing was encoded 


    Success!
```

The gotten metadata is as follows.

```
    ;FFMETADATA1
    major_brand=mp42
    minor_version=0
    compatible_brands=isommp42
    com.android.version=7.0
    encoder=Lavf57.25.100
```

I tried to rewrite metadata with the following command, but it was not reflected.

```
    -i C:\Users\ebiyuu1209\Desktop\test.mp4 -metadata "duration"="300" -c copy C:\Users\ebiyuu1209\Desktop\test2.mp4
```

The log is as follows.

```
    ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
      libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
      libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
      libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
      libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
      libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
      libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
      libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
      libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\ebiyuu1209\Desktop\test.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
        creation_time   : 2016-06-05T02:07:03.000000Z
      Duration: 00:03:00.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2737 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2478 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2016-06-05T02:07:03.000000Z
          handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
          encoder         : AVC Coding
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2016-06-05T02:07:03.000000Z
          handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
    Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\Users\ebiyuu1209\Desktop\test2.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
        duration        : 300
        encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 2478 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2016-06-05T02:07:03.000000Z
          handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
          encoder         : AVC Coding
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2016-06-05T02:07:03.000000Z
          handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame= 4331 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   60422kB time=00:03:00.67 bitrate=2739.6kbits/s speed= 776x    
    video:54653kB audio:5647kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.203344%


    Success!
```

Does anyone have a similar issue?

Comment: @llogan
Added command and complete log.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is or what you are trying to achieve. 1) I see no extraneous duration metadata in your original input. 2) Both durations of input and output are the same. 3) The extraneous duration metadata that you set appears to be present in your output.

Comment: @llogan
Certainly, extraneous duration metadata appears in the Log.
However, the gotten metadata does not include keys after "encoder".
In fact, the Android file manager also shows "0" for duration (although it can still play normally).

Comment: Seems like an X/Y problem. I don't think any player is going to refer to your custom duration metadata. It seems to me the real problem you are trying to solve is, "Why does Android file manager show a duration of 0 with MP4 files created from `ffmpeg`?". Does it properly show a duration for the original input file? What if you add the `-movflags +faststart` output option in your `ffmpeg` command?

Comment: @llogan
Android file manager shows 0 duration regardless of original input file duration.
Adding -movflags faststart did not solve the issue.

Comment: Does any input properly show duration in file manager?

Comment: @llogan
Durations other than videos created by FFmpeg are showed properly.

Comment: Provide a link to a file that does work. Try a more recent ffmpeg: 3.4.1 is old. Does the ffmpeg processed file work if you run it through mp4box?

Comment: After a detailed investigation, I found something strange in the video file before the merge, too.
I would like to investigate this cause first.
Thank you very much.